# UIView.animate with imageArray inside of UIScrollView but with effect like paging enable

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm new in Swift but I have some basic experience.
I have successfully created an animation with three images and they repeat themselves. But I would like the effect of this repetition to be like when you in attributes inspector of `UIScrollView` check paging enable.

Inside of options: `UIView.AnimationOptions` I tried different Constants but I can not find that suits me.

**My question: Can I animate image array like you swipe images in scroll view with paging enable?**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!

    var imageArray = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageArray = [UIImage(named: "forest")!, UIImage(named: "slika1")!, UIImage(named: "slika2")!]

        for i in 0..<imageArray.count {

            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.image = imageArray[i]
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let xPosition = self.miniView.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)

            mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
            mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        }

        startAnimating()
    }

    func startAnimating() {
        var newOffset = mainScrollView.contentOffset
        newOffset.x = 0.0
        newOffset.x += mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(imageArray.count - 1)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: Double(imageArray.count), delay: 5, options: [.repeat, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
            self.mainScrollView.contentOffset = newOffset
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to use `self.mainScrollView.setContentOffset(contentOffset: newOffset, animated: true)` 

rather than `UIView.animate(withDuration: Double(imageArray.count), delay: 5, options: [.repeat, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
        self.mainScrollView.contentOffset = newOffset
    })`
?

Comment: No I didn't try because I need animation that the pictures themselves move. With this code you send I don't have that effect. But thank you for trying to find a solution at least.

Comment: So, i don't understand what you are trying to say with "Can I animate image array like you swipe images in scroll view with paging enable", can you best explain?

Comment: Whit this code I post here I have animation where pictures move one after the other and it looks like they're on the tape. But I want to be displayed with small breaks between them so that to looks like you manually swipe UIScrollView with more pictures and check paging enable is ON.

Comment: ok, i got it. I'm doing some stuff and go to delivery it by answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if i correctly understand what you want, this is the correct answer.
Animate page by page, with a 5 seconds delay with one animation and another.

You need to use `Timer.scheduledTimer` to trigger method that scroll to the next page. With that solution, you can check paging enable ON, so the user can change the page itself.

I hope it helps

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!

        var imageArray = [UIImage]()

        var currentPage = 0

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            imageArray = [UIImage(named: "forest")!, UIImage(named: "slika1")!, UIImage(named: "slika2")!]

            for i in 0..<imageArray.count {

                let imageView = UIImageView()
                imageView.image = imageArray[i]
                imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                let xPosition = self.miniView.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
                imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)

                mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
                mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

            }

            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(startAnimating), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }

        @objc func startAnimating() {

           //that line check if the current page is the last one, and set it to the first, otherwise, it increment the currentPage
           self.currentPage = (self.currentPage == imageArray.count-1) ? 0 : self.currentPage+1


           var newOffset = mainScrollView.contentOffset
           newOffset.x = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(self.currentPage)

           self.mainScrollView.setContentOffset(newOffset, animated: true)
       }

    }
```

Comment: Yes, this has helped me a lot. Thank you very much. The 'Timer.scheduledTimer' func is greatly used, I met with that func but I did not use it in this way with a combination of the current page. Thank you for the quick solution

Comment: Happy to help you, can you select as the correct answer?